# How to make many payments

Tags: paypal, payment

I would like to know how I can make an app where users can sell things and within this they can charge through the same app either by credit card or paypal, the part that interests me is the payments, that is, I would like to have several payments to different users how could I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a normal [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client) in a [secure browser](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications) and specify a 'payee' recipient, [documented here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/)